# Azure Data Explorer - HowTo ingest source URI for blob when ingesting CSV data

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am ingesting CSV data from blob using event grid trigger, I need to ingest the BLOB URI as part of the process for auditing. Is this possible, unable to find any reference that indicates that this is possible?
These files are 3mb in size and land at 10k files a minute, I cannot use a function app to open the file and add the column with the bloburi to each row, this will be to slow.

Answer (score 0):

Kusto indeed doesn't support blob uri embedding as part of the ingestion process.
You may think of a solution where you write the relevant metadata as part of the blob payload.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).